# How to trigger a route from a timer

Tags: java, apache-camel, timertask

I want to trigger a route form a timer task. When the run method calls. I have use `ProducerTemplate` with the annotation `@Produce`. But it throws null point exception because of `producerTemplate` is null.

```
public class ReminderTask extends TimerTask {

    @Produce
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Exchange defaultExchange = new DefaultExchange(new DefaultCamelContext());
        producerTemplate.send("direct:simpleRoute", defaultExchange);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for the @Produce annotation to work your ReminderTask instance needs to be container managed (e.g. camel-spring, blueprint).

Otherwise, you must explicitly initialize your ProducerTemplate field from the CamelContext instance that defines your "direct:simpleRoute" endpoint.

It's difficult to further answer this question without knowing more about how your CamelContext is created (and managed).